# Site failing after update to Playa 4.4.2

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic

I'm in the process of updating my local and staging-environments to EE2.6. I've just updated Matrix, Wygwam and Playa to their latest (EE2.6 compatible) versions, and I'm now getting these errors on the front-end:

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'rel.parent_is_draft' in 'where clause'

SELECT DISTINCT(rel.child_entry_id) AS entry_id FROM exp_playa_relationships rel WHERE rel.parent_entry_id = 1 AND rel.parent_is_draft = 0 ORDER BY rel.rel_order

Filename: /Applications/MAMP/hqdocs/static/third_party/playa/mod.playa.php

Line Number: 739
```

Backend is functioning fine, all fields are displaying and saving as expected, just the front-end fails... Any thoughts?

Comment: If you're still running into this after following Anna's answer, please email support@pixelandtonic.com with Super Admin access and we'll help you out directly on site. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like the update for Playa didn't complete. The "rel.parent_is_draft" column isn't in the database.

Make sure you followed all the [**Playa update instructions**](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/installation.html) including this one:

**Go to Add-Ons → Fieldtypes → Playa to trigger Playa’s update script.**

Comment: Any advice for next steps considering I upgraded to 4.4.5 and when I go to Addons->Fieldtypes->Playa, I get this error message: 
    `A Database Error Occurred
    Error Number: 1060
    Duplicate column name 'parent_is_draft'
ALTER TABLE exp_playa_relationships ADD parent_is_draft INT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 AFTER parent_var_id
Filename: /[redacted]/application/third_party/playa/ft.playa.php
Line Number: 474` ? Thank you!

Comment: Well that’s strange, I just refreshed that page with the error and now it loaded fine, and now I am also not getting the error 1054 on the front end, either.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same thing happen -- had to comment out line 423:

```
            //$this->EE->db->query('ALTER TABLE exp_playa_relationships ADD parent_var_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AFTER parent_row_id, ADD INDEX (parent_var_id)');
```

That got me past that step and things got better. :)

TTFN
Travis