# Are the following addons compitable with EE 2.8.1

Tags: cartthrob, pixelandtonic, solspace, ce-image

Going to upgrade a site from EE 2.5.3 to 2.8.1

Are following addons compatible with EE 2.8.1?

- Assets
- Cartthrob
- Cartthrob Order Manager
- Channel Images
- Wygwam
- Playa
- Matrix
- Simple S3 Uploader
- CE Image
- AJW Export
- Profile:Edit
- Field Editor
- Ct Admin, User

Sorry to ask such question here. But I found many of those addons owner ask to post question here. Going to  tag the question by addon name.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am using following add-ons with EE2.8.1 from your list.

```
 1. Assets
 2. Cartthrob
 3. Cartthrob Order Manager
 4. Channel Images
 5. Wygwam
 6. Playa
 7. Matrix
 8. Profile:Edit
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch to manually update Simple S3 Uploader to work with 2.8.1 which can be found here:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/simple-s3-uploader/viewthread/12869

I'm finding errors on the backend of the server with Matrix at present.

I'd hold off to upgrading presently as there are many issues with addons not being updated to work correctly with 2.8.1.

Also there is an update page for Solspace addons to confirm if they are operating with the new version of EE:

http://www.solspace.com/software/compatibility

In other words, none of your current list of Solspace addons are ready yet.

Answer (score 0):

Playa is playing some tricks - it actually throwing errors when you try access it from CP field types.
Wygwam is working 
Freeform is working 
Matrix is working 
Channel images had some problems, but since I got in touch with their support and after replacing with edge version they sent me - everything ran fine.

The rest of your add-ons it seems I;m not using it

Comment: Playa also is working.

Comment: Well not for me. I tried upgrading to 4.4.5 on EE latest version. Everything seems to be fine at first look, but when you try to click playa from Fieldtypes - to actually run the upgrade scripts - it throws errors like:
'Duplicate column name "parent_var_id"'

Answer (score 0):

Since I use EE 2.7xxx field editor doesn't work anymore, even on a fresh install. Playa, Matrix, Wygwam, CE image works fine with EE2.8.1 installed, no problems related.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution of the problem with Playa upgrade from previous version to 4.4.5  and DB error when you try to configure the field type:

[is described here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/13711/993)

Same answer I've got from Pixel & Tonic support.

Answer (score 0):

I am using all these with EE2.9 with basically no issues:

```
Assets
Cartthrob
Cartthrob Order Manager
Wygwam
Playa
Matrix
CE Image
Profile:Edit
Field Editor
Ct Admin, User
```

The only one I am having issues with is Wygwam actually.  I am finding some pages are CPU spiking and then timing out **depending on the content in that field**.  I have to do some more testing and then will contact P & T about it, but if I remove the stashing of that field, the page loads quickly, add it back and it cpu spikes and never renders.

It's only on a few pages on the site, so it must be ?specific content related? - overall it's all working quite smoothly although I did need  to attend to some session/login/forms/xid hash stuff as this all changed a bit after 2.8.1 - see
[After upgrading to EE 2.9.0 my front-end login page no longer works](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24655/after-upgrading-to-ee-2-9-0-my-front-end-login-page-no-longer-works)

...and a few conditionals needed a bit of revising with the new conditionals parse, but all in all way less pain that I expected (2.7.2 -> 2.9 in my case)