# Can't login to CP after upgrading to 2.8.1, page refreshes

Tags: control-panel, cpanel

I'm unable to login to control panel after upgrading from EE2.7.2 to EE2.8.1. I've read many posts here and on Ellislab site but none of the solutions proposed seems to work for me. Interestingly, it only happens in production; locally works fine. I'm able to login.

THings I've tried are:

- deleted my expressionengine/cache/ dir
- added $config variables to my config (below)

  - $config['cookie_prefix'] = '';
  - $config['cookie_path'] = '';
  - $config['cookie_domain'] = 'julianomoreira.com';
  - $config['user_session_type'] = 'c';
  - $config['admin_session_type'] = 's';
  - $config['cookie_secure']  = 'n';
  - $config['expire_session_on_browser_close'] = 'y';

Thanks,

Juliano

Comment: For me, it was just a redirect saved on browsers history. I cleaned up the browser and everything did fine.

Comment: Can you list the things you've tried? Otherwise you're liable to get answers that it sounds like you have already explored. For instance, are you running Structure, and if so have you disabled that add-on's redirect after login feature?

Comment: See https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24655/after-upgrading-to-ee-2-9-0-my-front-end-login-page-no-longer-works and confirm you've tried all that?

Comment: @JeremyDaalder Yes, I've tried all that.

Comment: @DerekJones I'm not running Structure. Relatedly, before I upgraded to 2.8.1 I was having issues with Freeform not sending due to an issue with secure forms so I turned it off in the CP.

Comment: Try deleting your browser cookies and browser cache as well. You may want to put in a support ticket at EllisLab so our engineers can log in and debug it for you.

Comment: You don't mention the exp_sessions table clearing explicitly.  This is important so I repeat it just in case.

Comment: @DerekJones I deleted all my browser cookies and cache as well. I'm going to have to create a support ticket at Ellislab. Shoot!!! Thanks though!

Comment: @JeremyDaalder I cleared the exp_sessions table but it did not solve the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @DerekJones Interestingly enough, it only happens on production; locally I'm able to login fine.

Comment: I decided to roll back and upgrade my site one more time and now it works. I guess the take-away here is if you version control your EE site, then once you run the installer locally, you need to run it on prod as well. Not sure if this was the cause of my issue but it works now.

Comment: I had this same problem and can't get past it. Site works fine before upgrade, but once I run the install it won't work. It just redirects to the cp login page (/cp/index.php?/cp/login). Tried all the suggestions and still nothing.

Comment: @blenddev What's your system setup? Do you have a VCS running and a deployment script? If you do, once you push the code up to production remember to run admin.php in production once again. It worked for me.